# Rails Bundle Install failed with Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, rubygems, bundler

I tried installing Rails with docker, I got the below error

```
Installing websocket-driver 0.6.5 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/usr/local/bundle/gems/websocket-driver-0.6.5/ext/websocket-driver
/usr/local/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180911-15-1atjs2q.rb extconf.rb
Cannot allocate memory - /usr/local/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180911-15-1atjs2q.rb
extconf.rb 2>&1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/bundle/gems/websocket-driver-0.6.5
for inspection.
Results logged to
/usr/local/bundle/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/websocket-driver-0.6.5/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing websocket-driver (0.6.5), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install websocket-driver -v '0.6.5' --source
'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  rails was resolved to 5.1.6, which depends on
    actioncable was resolved to 5.1.6, which depends on
      websocket-driver
```

Here my docker file

```
FROM ruby:latest

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y curl

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install nodejs

RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN gem install rails

RUN  /app/bin/setup

RUN chmod -R 755 /app

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["bundle", "exec", "puma", "-C", "config/puma.rb","-e","alpha"]
```

I tried installing in my mac machine its working good. I bought a new ubuntu 16.04 server from the digital ocean and try installing the same. I got this error. I am using Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40.

In my app/bin/setup I'm running below commands

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'pathname'
require 'fileutils'
include FileUtils

# path to your application root.
APP_ROOT = Pathname.new File.expand_path('../../', __FILE__)

def system!(*args)
  system(*args) || abort("\n== Command #{args} failed ==")
end

chdir APP_ROOT do
  # This script is a starting point to setup your application.
  # Add necessary setup steps to this file.

  puts '== Installing dependencies =='
  system! 'gem install bundler --conservative'
  system('bundle check') || system!('bundle install')

  puts "\n== Removing old tempfiles =="
  system! 'bin/rails tmp:clear'

  puts "\n== Precompiling Assets =="
  system! 'bin/rails assets:precompile'

  puts "\n== Restarting application server =="
  system! 'bin/rails restart'
end
```

I tried with ruby:latest, ruby:2.4.1 nothing works.

After few suggestions I added sudo apt-get install ruby-dev in my Dockerfile but this also doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Cannot allocate memory - /usr/local/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180911-15-1atjs2q.rb
>   extconf.rb 2>&1

This line indicates that your Digital Ocean droplet doesn't have enough RAM to build your dependencies and therefore the docker build fails.

I've had the same problem and unfortunately you just need more resources.

Alternatively you could build the image, tag and push it to a docker repository then pull and run it on your DO droplet to avoid the build step.

Comment: This is the unfortunate answer, i ran into this as well. Before you upgrade your entire droplet, check what else is using memory. For me it was the current docker containers running `puma` web server and other things. You can analyze memory usage with `top` (hit shift + `>` once to sort by `MEM %`). Items that start in `bundle` are probably ruby processes started with `bundle exec`. I stopped the containers and rebuilt and it worked. While building I run this as a cheap way to capture available mem every second: `while sleep 1; do cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemFree >> ~/out; done`

Answer (score 1):

Use alpine version of ruby. It will consume much less space. For ex: `FROM ruby:2.5.1-alpine`